# Ubuntu 18.04 PXE Installer Crashing

Tags: 18.04, pxe

This problem is quite specific, but as I am only seeing this behavior on one type of hardware, and only on the 18.04 installation, I figured I'd reach out on here.

PXE booting an HPE DL20 Gen9 server into the Ubuntu 18.04 installer results in a crash.
I will not receive any error messages or feedback, it looks like the server will actually crash as even iLO becomes unreachable for a few seconds.

Does anyone have any kernel paramaters I might be able to play with?

My PXE server is set up with basic parameters, feeding the kernel and ramdisk to the server.

Thank you to anyone who offers a suggestion.

UPDATE: Fixed using an updated kernel/ramdisk available from the bionic-updates folders structure as opposed to their base one.

Comment: Are you using a model with a Core i3 or a Xeon? How much RAM is in the machine? Do you have any specific hardware, such as a fibre channel card, installed? A bit more info about the internals will make suggestions a heck of a lot more relevant 

Comment: 1240v5 Xeon, various amounts of RAM ranging from 8GB to 64GB. No additional hardware but the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using an updated kernel/ramdisk available from the bionic-updates folders structure as opposed to their base one.